# Difference in raster values between R and QGIS

Tags: pixel, raster, qgis

I want to ask what probably is a basic question about the way in which R and QGIS import raster files.

I have a single band-raster. When I import it into R, using the "raster" function of the raster package, I get this range of pixel values:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 10980, 10980, 120560400  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent      : 6e+05, 709800, 5590200, 5700000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=31 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : /data/MTDA/CGS_S2_RADIOMETRY/2017/10/15/S2B_20171015T104525Z_31UFS_TOC_V100/S2B_20171015T104525Z_31UFS_TOC-B02_10M_V100.tif 
names       : S2B_20171015T104525Z_31UFS_TOC.B02_10M_V100 
values      : -32768, 32767  (min, max)
```

When I stack this layer in a raster brick, I get these min-max values:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
band        : 2  (of  11  bands)
dimensions  : 10980, 10980, 120560400  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent      : 6e+05, 709800, 5590200, 5700000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=31 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : /tmp/Rtmp882dZS/raster/r_tmp_2017-11-10_172819_11532_86514.grd 

names       : S2B_20171015T104525Z_31UFS_TOC.B02_10M_V100 
values      : -1129, 9994  (min, max)
```

However, if I load the same raster in QGIS, the min value is 228 and the max value is 907 (I calculated these values with the options "Extent: Full" and "Accuracy: Actual (slower)".

So, where do these differences come from? I do not understand exactly what R and QGIS are doing...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, I found what is the difference about!
When asking to R, I get the real min/max values. QGIS, instead, calculates the min/max values with a cumulative count. When I set the "Load min/max values" (in the Raster Properties window) to "Min/Max" I got the same values R showed.

Answer (score 1):

For the first object, the min and max values are not known as the file does not provide them (or not correctly). With `RasterLayer` `r` you can do

```
 r <- setMinMax(r)
```

To see what they are. If they do not become the same as for the second layer you show, then you probably mixed something up. After clarifying these things, it might be useful to compare with QGIS. For that, you would probably need to provide an example file.